# Azure : Error 404: AciDeploymentFailed / Error 400 ACI Service request failed

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I am trying to deploy a machine learning model through an ACI (Azure Container Instances) service. I am working in Python and I followed the following code (from the official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=azcli) :

The entry script file is the following (score.py):

```
import os
import dill
import joblib

def init():
    global model
    # Get the path where the deployed model can be found
    model_path = os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR')

    # Load existing model
    model = joblib.load('model.pkl')

# Handle request to the service
def run(data):
    try:
        # Pick out the text property of the JSON request
        # Expected JSON details {"text": "some text to evaluate"}
        data = json.loads(data)
        prediction = model.predict(data['text'])
        return prediction
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        return error
```

And the model deployment workflow is as:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
# Connect to workspace
ws = Workspace(subscription_id="my-subscription-id",
               resource_group="my-ressource-group-name",
               workspace_name="my-workspace-name")


from azureml.core.model import Model
model = Model.register(workspace = ws,
                       model_path= 'model.pkl',
                       model_name = 'my-model',
                       description = 'my-description')


from azureml.core.environment import Environment
# Name environment and call requirements file
# requirements: numpy, tensorflow
myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(name = 'myenv', file_path = 'requirements.txt')

from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
# Create inference configuration
inference_config = InferenceConfig(environment=myenv, entry_script='score.py')

from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice #AksWebservice
# Set the virtual machine capabilities
deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 0.5, memory_gb = 3)


from azureml.core.model import Model
# Deploy ML model (Azure Container Instances)
service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                       name='my-service-name',
                       models=[model],
                       inference_config=inference_config,
                       deployment_config=deployment_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
```

I succeded once with the previous code. I noticed that during the deployment the Model.deploy created a container registry with a specific name (6e07ce2cc4ac4838b42d35cda8d38616).

### The problem:

The API was working well and I wanted to deploy an other model from scratch. I deleted the API service and model from Azure ML Studio and the container registry from Azure ressources.

Unfortunately I am not able to deploy again anything.

Everything goes fine until the last step (the Model.deploy step), I have the following error message :

> Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
>
> Operation ID: 46243f9b-3833-4650-8d47-3ac54a39dc5e
>
> More information can be found here: https://machinelearnin2812599115.blob.core.windows.net/azureml/ImageLogs/46245f8b-3833-4659-8d47-3ac54a39dc5e/build.log?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&sig=45kgNS4sbSZrQH%2Fp29Rhxzb7qC5Nf1hJ%2BLbRDpXJolk%3D&st=2021-10-25T17%3A20%3A49Z&se=2021-10-27T01%3A24%3A49Z&sp=r
>
> Error:
>
> {
>
> "code": "AciDeploymentFailed",
>
> "statusCode": 404,
>
> "message": "No definition exists for Environment with Name: myenv Version: Autosave_2021-10-25T17:24:43Z_b1d066bf Reason: Container > registry 6e07ce2cc4ac4838b42d35cda8d38616.azurecr.io not found. If private link is enabled in workspace, please verify ACR is part of private > link and retry..",
>
> "details": []
>
> }

I do not understand why the first time a new container registry was well created, but now it seems that it is sought (the message is saying that container registry identified by name 6e07ce2cc4ac4838b42d35cda8d38616 is missing). I never found where I can force the creation of a new container registry ressource in Python, neither specify a name for it in AciWebservice.deploy_configuration or Model.deploy.

Does anyone could help me moving on with this? The best solution would be I think to delete totally this 6e07ce2cc4ac4838b42d35cda8d38616 container registry but I can't find where the reference is set so Model.deploy always fall to find it.

An other solution would be to force Model.deploy to generate a new container registry, but I could find how to make that.

It's been 2 days that I am on this and I really need your help !

PS : I am not at all a DEVOPS/MLOPS guy, I make data science and good models, but infrastructure and deployment is not really my thing so please be gentle on this part ! :-)

### What I tried

#### Creating the container registry with same name

I tried to create the container registry by hand, but this time, this is the container that cannot be created. The Python output of the Model.deploy is the following :

> Tips: You can try get_logs(): https://aka.ms/debugimage#dockerlog or local deployment: https://aka.ms/debugimage#debug-locally to debug if deployment takes longer than 10 minutes.
>
> Running
>
> 2021-10-25 19:25:10+02:00 Creating Container Registry if not exists.
>
> 2021-10-25 19:25:10+02:00 Registering the environment.
>
> 2021-10-25 19:25:13+02:00 Building image..
>
> 2021-10-25 19:30:45+02:00 Generating deployment configuration.
>
> 2021-10-25 19:30:46+02:00 Submitting deployment to compute.
>
> Failed
>
> Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
>
> Operation ID: 93780de6-7662-40d8-ab9e-4e1556ef880f
>
> Current sub-operation type not known, more logs unavailable.
>
> Error:
>
> {
>
> "code": "InaccessibleImage",
>
> "statusCode": 400,
>
> "message": "ACI Service request failed. Reason: The image '6e07ce2cc4ac4838b42d35cda8d38616.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_684133370d8916c87f6230d213976ca5' in container group 'my-service-name-LM4HbqzEBEi0LTXNqNOGFQ' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#admin-account and make sure Admin user is enabled for your container registry."
>
> }

#### Setting admin user enabled

I tried to follow the recommandation of the last message saying to set Admin user enabled for the container registry. All what I saw in Azure interface is that a username and password appeared when enabling on user admin.

Unfortunately the same error message appears again if I try to relaunche my code and I am stucked here...

#### Changing name of the environment and model

This does not produces any change. Same errors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @FLS, I know it's a few months old, but do you remember resolving this? Encountered the same issue and no solution has worked..

Comment: @CallumMatthews as far as I remember, I deleted my AzureML ressource and recreated it from scratch. It was actually something with Azure messing with updating the docker ressource with the container registry, but I never found how to make the link again

Answer (score 0):

As you tried with first attempt it was worked. After deleting the API service and model from Azure ML Studio and the container registry from Azure resources you are not able to redeploy again.

My assumption is your first attempt you are already **register** the `Model` Environment variable. So when you try to ***reregister*** by using the `same model` name while deploying it will gives you the error.

Thanks @ [anders swanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3842610/anders-swanson) Your solution worked for me.

If you have already registered your env, `myenv`, and none of the details of the your environment have changed, there is no need re-register it with `myenv.register()`. You can simply get the already register env using [`Environment.get()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.environment?view=azure-ml-py#get-workspace--name--version-none-) like so:

```
myenv = Environment.get(ws, name='myenv', version=11)
```

My Suggestion is to name your environment as new value.

`"model_scoring_env"`. Register it once, then pass it to the `InferenceConfig`.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459278/15997690)

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately after having tested what you proposed, the problem persists. I updated my initial post to track tests made.